# Polynomial Hierarchy - the difference between $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$

Tags: complexity-theory

The way I understand is that complexity classes which are denoted with $\Sigma_i$ are representing a combination of alternating variable quantifiers which must start with an existential quantifier $\exists$, for example: $\exists y_1 \forall y_2 ... Q y_i$ and the last quantifier does not really matter. That is why we can say that $\Sigma_1 P \subseteq \Sigma_2 P$ because the last quantifier can act as a dummy quantifier.

However, what bothers me in my understanding is the example when we say that $\Pi_1 P \subseteq \Sigma_2 P$. In my understanding the variables $y$ are ordered and hence in $\Pi_1 P$ we state that this is true for every $y_1$ whereas in $\Sigma_2 P$ we state that this is true only for some $y_1$ which is much less restrictive.

By any chance, is my reasoning that $y$ variables are ordered false? In that case I would understand that we can just add a dummy quantifier up front just like we did in the first example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conception of the variable ordering is misleading you, and we can indeed add a dummy variable at the beginning.

If we have a $\Pi_1\mathrm{P}$-problem $S$, we can write it as $S(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall y_1 Q(x,y_1)$. But then of course we also have that $S(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists y_1 \forall y_2 \ Q(x,y_2)$, and thus conclude that $S \in \Sigma_2\mathrm{P}$.

Comment: Ohh I see, so as long as the variable itself is a dummy on that does not impact the value of $S$ we can basically add it either at the front or at the end?
And thanks for the nice answer!